# Kotlin: start an Activity from a fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I tried to **start an Activity from a fragment** (with setOnClickListener), but it doesn't work. I start this fragment from an Activity, in a FrameLayout :

```
btn.setOnClickListener {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.FrameLayout,
                FirstFragment()
            )
            .commit()
        }
```

Here is my fragment code:

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

    return inflater . inflate (R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
}
```

I searched a lot and found much code but nothing worked.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: To start an activity, call `startActivity()`.

Comment: There is no second `Activity`, to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You have to try this:

after \

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

```
val v:View inflater . inflate (R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
val btnCallFragment = v.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn)
btnCallFragment.setOnClickListener{
   startActivity(Intent(activity,MainActivity::class.java))
} return v } }
```

Comment: Change the MainActivity to the activity you want move

Answer (score 0):

You never start Activities from Fragments. The navigation control is Activity responsability.

To start any Component in Android you need a Intent.

Here find the official documentation:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=es#CommunicatingWithActivity